# Update aws_lambda function via terraform without deleting the previous version?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm trying to create an **ES cluster and lambda** function using **terraform** as part of a pipeline.

My use-case involves uploading a zip file for aws_lambda with dependencies.
The `lambda_function.py` is invoking an ES endpoint which needs to be updated with the latest endpoint after terraform creation.

**Issue**
Output from terraform is shown only after creation of the ES cluster (approx after 10 min), whereas lambda is created in 5 seconds.

So updating the zip mid script is out of the picture.

Now that leaves me with updating just the lambda with an updated zip file but I need to ensure that re-running terraform doesn't delete the previous created resources.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now that leaves me with updating just the lambda with an updated zip file but I need to ensure that re-running terraform doesn't delete the previous created resources.

Terraform won't destroy resources if you re-run it unless you explicitly calling destroy. It will update the resources if there is any change.

1. We can use explicit [Terraform depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies) clause and pass the final ES endpoint to the lambda definition in terraform as ENV variable.
2. Manage both as separate terraform modules, the ES module will eventually store the value of ES endpoint in the AWS parameter store and then the Lambda module can reference it or pass it as an ENV var.